# Pandas : Fill null in multiple columns only if another column is null

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which has 86 columns. There are columns with prefixes such as `name_smt1, name_smt2, ..., status_smt1, status_smt2,..., grade_smt1, grade_smt2,...` and so. Other columns are subjects, and there are more than 40 subjects columns with different names.  I also have this one column named `grade_t` which I use as a parameter whether I will fill all the subjects columns those contain with `D` or no. If the column `grade_t` in a row is null then all of subjects columns (which is null) will be filled with `D`. I'm trying to do it like this but it raised error saying `ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (7,4) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (7,)` is there any way to do this without the code below? I have been working on this for 2 days, I have tried looping over it but it resulting in filling all of subjects with `D` even when the `IP_t` is not null

```
merged_df.loc[merged_df['IP_t'].isnull(),matkul] = merged_df[merged_df['IP_t'].isnull()][matkul].fillna(value='D')
```

Full code

```
merged_df['TARGET'] = merged_df['TARGET'].fillna(value='TIDAK LULUS')

list_nama_prefix = [col for col in merged_df.columns if 'NAMA_' in col and not 'NAMA_smt1' in col]

merged_df = merged_df.drop(list_nama_prefix,1)
merged_df = merged_df.rename(columns={
    'NAMA_smt1' : 'NAMA'
})

list_ip = [col for col in merged_df.columns if 'IP_' in col]
smt_sebelumnya_cols = [col for col in merged_df.columns if 'STATUS LULUS SMT SEBELUMNYA_' in col]
smt_skrg_cols = [col for col in merged_df.columns if 'STATUS LULUS SMT SEKARANG_' in col]
status_sp_cols = [col for col in merged_df.columns if 'Status SP_' in col]
statuses = smt_sebelumnya_cols+status_sp_cols+smt_skrg_cols
matkul = merged_df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).drop(statuses,1).columns.tolist()
list_matkul = [i for i in matkul if i not in ('NIM', 'NAMA','TARGET')]

merged_df.loc[merged_df['IP_t'].isnull(),matkul] = merged_df[merged_df['IP_t'].isnull()][matkul].fillna(value='D')
```

My [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FWWMurFXiWwFAdpDCWJOWoeF8ZtLs_rdKrFX3LqEK-o/edit#gid=187745994) if you'd like to see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I understand your problem correctly, given input

```
   grade_t subject_1 subject_2  other
0      NaN        A+       NaN    1.0
1      1.0        B-         B    NaN
2      NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN
3      1.0       NaN         A    4.0
```

You want the output to be

```
   grade_t subject_1 subject_2  other
0      NaN         D         D    1.0
1      1.0        B-         B    NaN
2      NaN         D         D    NaN
3      1.0       NaN         A    4.0
```

If so I think this is done most easily using the `mask` method:

```
mask = data['grade_t'].isna()
subject_columns = ['subject_1', 'subject_2']
data[subject_columns] = data[subject_columns].mask(mask, other='D', axis=0)
```

`df.mask(cond, other)` takes a boolean mask `cond` and value `other`, and replaces the values of `df` with `other` wherever `cond` is True, and retains the original value from `df` everywhere else.

In general, `cond` can be a DataFrame of the same shape as `data`, or a Series whose index matches the index or columns of `df`, in which case you should specify the `axis` argument (as in the snippet above).

Comment: hello, thanks for helping me also explaining the code clearly